# Can't remove open logical volume

Tags: linux

I am trying to remove a logical volume but it is throwing the error:

Can't remove open logical volume "TestDeliveries"

does anyone know the problem

Comment: You should compose questions so that everyone can easily understand your problem and suggest the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.

```
while [ $? -eq "5" ]; do lvremove -f /dev/vg_laptop/lv_home ; 
done 
Can't remove open logical volume "lv_home" 
Can't remove open logical volume "lv_home" 
Can't remove open logical volume "lv_home" 
Logical volume "lv_home" successfully removed
```

From https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=577798